# Can not visit some sites because of too many ads! Is there any virus in my Mac?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, safari

I need to know that my mac was working perfectly fine till today. I wanted to visit same sites which i have visited yesterday in safari,and they were working perfectly fine, so today when i tried to open the page. It opened for few seconds and then went to another page of ads, where i couldn't see any cross option to close this ad. I have tried other sites to check ,but sadly same thing occurred. Only main site like mac,Facebook and this site working fine.

Need to fix this issue. Is there any virus. I didn't install anything in mac.

[image: AdsImage]

Comment: Can you add some samples for sites showing too many ads?

Comment: lang-8.com, http://ielts.studyhorror.com/ielts-writing-graphs

Comment: Do you have another browser like Firefox or Chrome to try?

Comment: Yes, I have chrome ,but same problem with these site. In chrome,Imdb.com  also  pop ups video ads. I am sick of it. Some time i can't see where the voice coming from in chrome, so i have to close tabs.

Comment: I tried the two sites you listed and had no issues. If it's happening with Chrome and you're getting the same ads/browser-jacking, logging in to another user account would be one thing to try. There's also the (small) chance that your ISP is doing some heavy ad-insertion..

Comment: so what is the solution. How to fix it?

Comment: Do you have another user account that you can log into on the machine? What other troubleshooting have you done? What have you installed recently - new/updated software? What kind of network are you on? Where? Details, need you to provide details - we're not sitting next to you, remember. ;)

Comment: No, i do not have any other account. Updated Yosemite and Xcode and didn't install any thing except rar extract free from iTune. I am in saudi and using WiFi.

Comment: You could certainly boot into Recovery mode and reinstall the system, but you'd want to make sure that you have a good backup of your files before doing that. If you're on some type of public WiFi, that could be very suspect as well.

Comment: Its not a public wifi. And why reinstall for just ads? its a long procedure and i don't wanna do. Sure there is another option.

Comment: And can you add a new user to your Mac (can be done in System Preferences) and login as the new user to see whether the problem occurs there as well?

Comment: I  added one image of ad. You mean i should login as guest user? I have guest user.

Comment: Guest user is ok as well (but creating a new user is just a 30 seconds task anyway)

Comment: OK, I made new user and logged in  ,and checked same sites in safari. It worked perfectly fine there. Now suggest me what to do,except reinstallation?

Comment: try the 3 free tools listed in my answer below [back on your own account]

Comment: I have heard that mac does not need any anti viruses.Any way, i dowloaded adware removal tool. After search it said no adware found. Now what?

Comment: Ok, I have cleaned my mac by using Bitdefender. It said that two adware have found and has been deleted, but still problem was there. I went to safari Extension and found only one extension there , which was by the name of MacCoupon, so i unInstalled it. Then went to chrome even though it was enable in chrome but i deleted and restart safari. It worked perfectly fine. I am happy that i didnt reinstall my mac for just ads. Also no anti viruses worked for me. Going to deleted them all.

Answer (score 1):

Try BitDefender's [freeware tools](http://www.bitdefender.com/toolbox/freeapps/desktop/) -

Adware Removal Tool for Mac
Virus scanner for Mac
Mechanic

The Adware remover you get directly from the link, the others you can get through Apple's App Store.

I would highly recommend keeping the Virus scanner on your machine afterwards & running it periodically.
Macs are not immune to viruses, they're just rare.
The freeware version does not actively scan in the background, you need the paid version for that.

BitDefender is highly rated on **official** antivirus test sites such as http://www.av-test.org/en/